# Subsequence with minimal absolute value

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming

This is an interview question. Given an integer array find a subsequence (not necessarily contiguous) for which the absolute value of the sum of its elements is minimized.

It looks like a DP problem.

- Let `S1[i]` is a subsequence ending at `a[i]` for which its sum > 0 and *abs*(sum) is minimized.
- Let `S2[i]` is a subsequence ending at `a[i]` for which its sum < 0  and *abs*(sum) is minimized.
- `S1[i]` is the minimum of all `S1[j] + a[i]` for `j < i` if `S1[j] + a[i]` > 0 &&  `a[i]` < 0
- `S2[i]` is the minimum of all `S2[j] + a[i]` for `j < i` if `S2[j] + a[i]` < 0 &&  `a[i]` > 0

Once we now `S1[i]` and `S2[i]` for all indexes it is easy to find the subsequence with the mininimal absolute value of its elements.

Does it make sense?

Comment: As the empty sub-sequence is not excluded, it is a trivial solution of the problem as stated. Any longer sub-sequence then qualifies only if the sum of its elements == 0. Is the problem perhaps incompletely stated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the minimum absolute sum among non-empty subsequences. (Otherwise as mentioned in the comments, the empty subsequence has sum 0.)

Since the order of the elements doesn't matter, your question just asks: given a (multi)set of elements, what is the minimum absolute sum among all subsets. It is easy to see that the [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) reduces to this problem. Since subset sum is NP-hard so is this problem. Therefore, it is a good bet that your polynomial time algorithm is wrong. Otherwise, P = NP.

In fact, a counterexample to your algorithm is the input sequence {-1, 2, -2}.

[Standard approaches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution) to the subset sum problem can be used to obtain pseudo-polynomial time algorithms for your problem.

Comment: Actually, given that the original post is an interview question , maybe the empty subsequence IS the correct answer.  Not a great question though, as it requires an Ah-Ha! answer.

Comment: The order of elements _does_ matter in this problem.

Comment: @Michael Consider a bag (or multiset) containing the array elements. It is easy to see that subsets of the bag are in one-one correspondence with subsequences of the array. Since 'sum' is associative and commutative, the sum of a subset is equal to the sum of the corresponding subsequence.

Answer (score 1):

I wish I could follow your reasoning but I'm a little slow...also you asked for DP and here's Haskell again...but is this what you mean?

```
import Data.List (sortBy, subsequences)
import Data.Ord (comparing)

minValSub xs = 
  head $ sortBy (comparing snd) 
  $ map (\x -> (x, abs (sum x)) ) (filter (not . null) $ subsequences xs)


OUTPUT:
*Main> minValSub [1,2,3,-4,5]
([1,3,-4],0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming non-empty result sets.

Let the list of integers be S. Consider the smallest **absolute** value among them S[k]. If S[K] == 0 return it. Else the goal is to find a value smaller than S[K].

Divide the integers into two sets of positive and negative integers as you mentioned SP (non-negative) and SN. Now find the sum in SP which is as close to another sum in SN by less than S[K]. This can be done by sorting the elements in SP and SN separately on absolute values, keeping a sum and a head pointer on each list. You can fill in the details.

This could give something that is lesser than S[K], else report S[K].

For example:
S = {1, -4, 2, -8, 5, -7}
k = 0, S[k] = 1

SP (sorted) = {1, 2, 5}
SN (sorted) = {-4, -7, -8}

Traversing the two arrays simultaneously you can get some candidates {1,2} and {-4} which will give the same result as S[k]. but {2,5} and {-7} will be better giving a net sum of 0.