# Pseudo code for an algorithm that finds the following sum?

Tags: algorithm

Given a finite sequence a1,a2,....,an of integers (which can be negative or positive), a segment of it is defined as ai,.....aj for i >= 1 and j <= n. I am trying to create an algorithm that can find the minimum sum of all segments, in other words, for **each of all** possible segments that can be made out of the sequence, sum their respective terms and make a set composed of every sum that you obtained. To try to make it clearer, if sum_a is the sum of the segment a1 and sum_b is the sum of a1,a2 and so on for all the possible segments, then of all the sums that I obtain, what would pseudo code to find the minimum sum of all the segment sums?

More specifically, how can I find the minimum **positive** sum?

Comment: how are i and j defined? if i can be equal to j then min number from list is your sum!

Comment: Define "segment". And please reformat your question, it's very hard to read

Comment: @Nullpointer Since individual elements can be negative, that's not true. In `[-1,3]`, the minimum positive sum is `2`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subsequence with minimal absolute value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343500/subsequence-with-minimal-absolute-value)

Comment: @TylerDurden That question is about noncontiguous subsequences, which makes it a subset sum problem. This one is about *ranges* (n^2 max), which makes it quite a bit different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure that I understood you correctly:

```
cur_best = +infinity
cur_best_start = 1
cur_best_end = n
for start = 1..n:
    for end = start..n:
        sum_subsequence = 0
        for i = start..end:
            sum_subsequence = sum_subsequence + a_i
        if (sum_subsequence > 0) and (sum_subsequence < cur_best):
            cur_best = sum_subsequence
            cur_best_start = start
            cur_best_end = end
```

The minimum of all subsquences of `a` that are positive.

Comment: What do you mean by for start = 1..n? loop for all the values from 1 to n?

Comment: @LanceFerd `for start = 1..n` shall mean "iterate over all `start`s for `start` in `1` to `n`".